# Why don't I get any compiler warnings in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, compiler-warnings

I recently switched to Xcode 4.5 and I no longer receive realtime compiler warnings. I only receive the warnings after building my project. I can literally type in "laskjflskdjf" and get no errors until compile time.

Additionally, after building a project, receiving a warning, and resolving the issue, the yellow or red warning icon is not removed until I build the project again.

Are there build settings that I must manually adjust to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: In my experience the warnings may or may not occur, at the whim of Xcode.

Comment: Expanding on that, a local variable, unused, will pretty reliably produce the "unreferenced" warning, and the warning will go away as soon as you add a reference.  Other warnings, eg, about instance variables that are the wrong type, often only appear after a build, and don't go away until the next build.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4.5.2, the option is in Preferences > General > Show live issues. I was able to reproduce what you describe by unchecking this option.

Comment: That would seem to make sense, but that option was already checked. For some reason it doesn't work? I'm baffled.

Comment: Seems like something may be wrong with your Xcode. I'd try wiping it out and reinstalling. Please report back if you try that.

Comment: I reinstalled it and oddly enough I only have this problem only with one Xcode project. It's my most important project and I don't understand what could be happening..

Comment: Very strange but it sounds like progress. My next suggestion would be to rebuild the project.